# Launch ubuntu.exe from windows cmd in current working dir

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have recently installed Ubuntu from the windows store and I don't seem to be able to launch it in the CWD from a windows cmd like I could with the legacy bash shell

The legacy/beta bash shell automatically puts me in my current dir like this:

```
C:\dev\repos>bash
kirlac@XPS-15-9550:/mnt/c/dev/repos$
```

But for some reason the ubuntu shell doesn't and always just dumps me in my home dir instead:

```
C:\dev\repos>ubuntu
kirlac@XPS-15-9550:~$
```

Is there any configuration i can set or args I can provide to get the same behaviour as the legacy bash shell instead of having to `cd` to the appropriate dir after it launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use command `ubuntu run /bin/bash`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted. It even works from the windows explorer address bar to open an ubuntu console in the current dir